# Are callbacks in Mesos Scheduler thread-safe?

Tags: scheduler, mesos

Does each call back to scheduler from mesos master gets run in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple callbacks on the same scheduler will never be invoked simultaneously -- i.e., if a second event is delivered for a scheduler while a previous scheduler callback is still active, the second callback will not be invoked until the first callback completes. Note that this implies you should avoid performing blocking or long-running operations in scheduler callbacks -- a typical pattern is to dispatch an asynchronous operation in the callback.